# SQL: Group by multiple columns and select first non null values for remaining multiple columns

Tags: sql

How to obtain the right table as output when the left table is given as input. I want to group by prod and geo columns and fetch the first not null value for all the rules columns.

[image]

I have tried this approach:

```
SELECT prod, geo,
(SELECT rule_1 FROM temp WHERE rule_1 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1) as rule_1,
(SELECT rule_2 FROM temp WHERE rule_2 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1) as rule_2,
(SELECT rule_3 FROM temp WHERE rule_3 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1) as rule_3,
(SELECT rule_4 FROM temp WHERE rule_4 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1) as rule_4
FROM temp
GROUP BY prod, geo
```

But somehow this is working only for first prod geo combination and not for subsequent combinations

Comment: This is not a free code/script writing service but a question and answer site for specific programming-related issues.
Hence you have to try it on your own first, and when stuck, come back here, edit your question and provide a minimal reproducible example of your coding attempts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please take the tour and read How to Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added the code that I tried. Could you please suggest some new approach to the existing code in order to deal with the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

[Alias the table in your query and update the filter](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8u4DC7ah3HBwPHztZ5RQc8/1) in the subqueries to exclude records that are not of the current group.

```sql
SELECT prod,
       geo,

  (SELECT rule_1
   FROM test
   WHERE rule_1 IS NOT NULL
     -- exclude records not of the current grouping
     AND t.prod = test.prod
     AND t.geo = test.geo
   LIMIT 1) AS rule_1,

  (SELECT rule_2
   FROM test
   WHERE rule_2 IS NOT NULL
     AND t.prod = test.prod
     AND t.geo = test.geo
   LIMIT 1) AS rule_2,

  (SELECT rule_3
   FROM test
   WHERE rule_3 IS NOT NULL
     AND t.prod = test.prod
     AND t.geo = test.geo
   LIMIT 1) AS rule_3,

  (SELECT rule_4
   FROM test
   WHERE rule_4 IS NOT NULL
     AND t.prod = test.prod
     AND t.geo = test.geo
   LIMIT 1) AS rule_4
FROM test AS t -- alias the table.
GROUP BY prod,
         geo;
```